# Using an en-dash for multiple author citations with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

The package `natbib` renders a citation with two authors Kashiwara and Schapira, for example, as

```
(Kashiwara and Schapira)
```

when I use the command `\citep*`.
Is it possible to have it output "(Kashiwara-Schapira)" instead, separated by a hyphen (en-dash)?
(Of course I could use an alias but this is the worst case.)

Comment: The form of the connector between two names in a citation is not governed by `natbib` but by the bibliography style employed in the document. What's in the argument of your document's `\bibliographystyle{...}` command?

Comment: @Mico, I see.  My bibliography style is `plainnat`.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Mico's tip, I have patched the plainnat.bst file provided with `natbib`.  See the modified version [here](https://gist.github.com/adeel/6659312) and the diff [here](https://gist.github.com/adeel/6659312/revisions).  Hopefully I didn't introduce any bugs, but it seems to be working as desired.

Comment: Are these modifications doing a job on the way the authors' names are displayed in the bibliography?

Comment: @Mico, no, the formatting in the bibliography didn't change (as I wanted).